# Graphene pydantic 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, graphene-python

I'm using FastApi with graphene, and graphene-pydantic.
When I try to create an object, i.e :

```
mutation createZone {
 createZone(zoneDetails: {
   zoneFr: "test fr",
   zoneEn: "test en",
    })
    {
     id
     zoneFr
     zoneEn
   }
   }
```

I get the error :

```
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

My mutation is :

```
class CreateZone(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        zone_details = ZoneGrapheneInputModel()

    Output = ZoneGrapheneModel

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(parent, info, zone_details):
        zone = Zone()
        zone.zoneFr = zone_details.zoneFr
        zone.zoneEn = zone_details.zoneEn
        zone.save()
        return zone
```

I'm also using Orator to create tables via CLI, am I missing something ?
Thanks

EDIT 1 :
My connection goes like this :

```
DATABASES = {
    "mysql": {
        "driver": "mysql",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "database": "test_db",
        "user": "root",
        "password": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "port": 3306
    }
}

db = DatabaseManager(DATABASES)
schema = Schema(db)
Model.set_connection_resolver(db)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I changed `from orator import Model` to `from db import Model` in models generated by Orator.